# Delete from temporary tables takes 100% CPU for a long time

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

I have a pretty complex query where we make use of a temporary table (this is in Oracle running on AWS RDS service).

```
INSERT INTO TMPTABLE (inserts about 25.000 rows in no time)
SELECT FROM X JOIN TMPTABLE (joins with temp table also in no time)
DELETE FROM TMPTABLE (takes no time in a copy of the production database, up to 10 minutes in the production database)
```

If I change the delete to a truncate it is as fast as in development.
So this change I will of course deploy. But I would like to understand why this occurs. AWS team has been quite helpful but they are a bit biased on AWS and like to tell me that my 3000 USD a month database server is not fast enough (I don't think so). I am not that fluent in Oracle administration but I have understood that if the redo logs are constantly filled, this can cause issues. I have increased the size quite substantially, but then again, this doesn't really add up.

Comment: As you say inserting into the temporary table takes little time why bother with it. Just use the query which drives the insert in the join of your real query. Then you can forget about the deletion altogether.

Comment: Note that `delete` and `truncate` are very different operations. `delete` is transactional (can be rolled back), and can (and usually should) use a `where` clause. `truncate` is DDL (i.e. it causes an implicit commit before and after it runs), requires a full table lock, cannot be rolled back, and removes all the data in the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly standard issue when deleting large amounts of data. The `delete` operation has to modify each and every row individually. Each row gets deleted, added to a transaction log, and is given an LSN.

`truncate`, on the other hand, skips all that and simply deallocates the data in the table.

You'll find this behavior is consistent across various RDMS solutions. Oracle, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, and MySQL will all have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, yes, but still, a 100% CPU for 10 minutes to delete some data (25000 numbers basically so no blobs or stuff)? I could accept if it was millions of records.

Comment: @JJohansson: What the contents of the rows are is more or less irrelevant. This is a standard issue with RDMSs. There's little more that can be answered here without a lot more information.

Comment: OK thanks... so then it is only down to figuring out why the production server can't handle it while the must weaker dev environment has no problems. I assume this boils down to the size of the transaction log. I can see there are about 12 transaction log switches per hour, not sure if that is normal since it has that count even when noone is using the database.

Comment: @JJohansson: If I had to offer a guess, I'd say that it's probably related to server load, backup settings, or replication.

Comment: ah replication.. that is actually a difference to DEV.. the production one is marked as a "multi az" which means the data is synchronously copied to another location.. thanks for the ideas

Comment: @JJohansson: That replication is probably your issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an Oracle Global Temporary table. They are fast, and don't need to be explicitly deleted after the session ends.

For example:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_T     
  (
    ID NUMBER(32)       
  )
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633

Comment: Thanks yes this is a global temp table, due to some logic it was created with PRESERVE instead of DEL after commit... food for thought would be to alter that logic to avoid implicit delete..